# Artifactory: TFS Release task won't download, but corresponding jfrog-cli command works fine

Tags: tfs, artifactory, release, jfrog-cli

I'm using:

- TFS 2017 Update 3
- JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension-1.6.2
- jfrog-cli version: 1.26.2

If I log into the build server using the build service account, and execute the following command line, it works:

`D:\agent\TFS_AGENT_work\r2\a>d:\agent\TFS_AGENT_work\_jfrog\current\jfrog.exe rt dl --url=http://FQDN:PORT/artifactory/ --recursive --include-dirs=true --user=USER --password=PASSWORD {black-box}/{grey-box}/ "d:\\agent\\TFS_AGENT_work\\r2\\a/"`

The "{black-box}" and "{grey-box}" are the same as the colored boxes in the screenshots below.

Here's what the release task looks like:
[image]

Here's the artifactory service config:
[image]

If I add a trailing `/` at the end of the server URL, like I have in my command, the connection verification fails.

The release tasks seems like it runs fine, but the files are not actually downloaded.  Here's the output :

...
[image]
...
[image: output-of-release-task]

I tried this many times.  I verified each time that the files were definitely not downloaded.

I also tried:

- adding "/" at the front of my {black-box} in the Spec, thinking maybe
  there was a missing slash after the artifactory url, but that didn't
  help
- removing the trailing "/" in the "target" json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include-dirs doesn't go in props; I must have misread the [docs](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) earlier

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "pattern": "{black-box}/{grey-box}/",
      "target": "$(Agent.ReleaseDirectory)\\",
      "recursive": "true",
      "include-dirs": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```